# Validate 0.5 as Step Value in HTML5 Number Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have an input field which only allows to type whole numbers or .5 decimal numbers. e.g. 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5.......etc etc

I am trying to do this with a HTML5 input field as so

`<input type="number" min="0" max="18" step="0.5" pattern="\d+" />`

but it won't validate the number when it is on a half step of 0.5. It just stays red when clicking outside / validating.

Is this possible? I can't find similar example of how to validate for half steps. DO I need to use jQuery to achieve this?

Thanks

Fiddle Demo http://jsfiddle.net/b8NrE/906/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove the `pattern` attribute. This is used for complex validation that requires regular expressions (and your regular expression is only matching sequences of digits). As it is, stipulating `min`, `max`, and `step` already define all the validation that you need:

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="18" step="0.5" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8NrE/907/

Comment: Cheers mate, should of thought of that!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this: It will clear text box if step is not .5

```html
<input type="number" min="0" oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"  step="0.5" />
```